# How to write a script that uses another software (in Windows)

Tags: windows, scripting, ocr

I'm new to script writing. So I wanted to know if it's possible to write a script that uses another software in the process. For example, I need to run a script to process a directory of images using an OCR software and store the output in another file.

It is possible to do so? And if so, how can I call the software in the script? For instance, if I want to use Adobe's scan to pdf function or ABBYY text grabber?

Comment: You need to read the documentation for the program to see if it supports scripting.

Comment: The programs I want to use don't support scripting :/

Comment: Then you're reduced to automation, which is not as reliable. If the application supports Active Accessibility or UI Automation (most do), you could use those automation interfaces. But describing how to use those interfaces is too broad for a Q&A format.